# Hadoop secondary sort (setPartitioner vs setOutputValueGroupingComparator)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to grok the necessity for the setOutputValueGroupingComparator method for a secondary sort - will not a setPartitioner be sufficient?

Say my input files have the following fields: customerId, orderId, orderDate, orderAmount

The expected output is the **last** order for **each** customer

I set up a key comparator using setOutputKeyComparatorClass() which will compare by **customerId asc, orderDate desc**

And a partitioner using setPartitioner() which will partition by **customerId % numPartition**

Here is sample keys which will be sent if number of reducers is 2:

```
key1: { customerId : 1, orderDate : 2012-01-31 } => reducer 1
key2: { customerId : 1, orderDate : 2011-12-31 } => reducer 1    
key3: { customerId : 2, orderDate : 2011-12-01 } => reducer 2    
key4: { customerId : 3, orderDate : 2012-02-01 } => reducer 1
```

My questions are:

a) With just the above partitioner, Is it possible for keys to be sent to reducer 1 in following (wrong) order? Here **customer 3 is interleaved with customer 1**

```
key1: { customerId : 1, orderDate : 2012-01-31 } => reducer 1
key4: { customerId : 3, orderDate : 2012-02-01 } => reducer 1
key2: { customerId : 1, orderDate : 2011-12-31 } => reducer 1
```

b) If yes, will setting a setOutputValueGroupingComparator (that compares the customerId in the key) fix this and send it in the correct order to the reducer?

```
key1: { customerId : 1, orderDate : 2012-01-31 } => reducer 1
key2: { customerId : 1, orderDate : 2011-12-31 } => reducer 1
key4: { customerId : 3, orderDate : 2012-02-01 } => reducer 1
```

Thanks

Ajai

Answer (score 2):

First off, read this: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html

The partitioner decides which keys go to which reducers.  So if you have keys A,B,C and D, and reducers 1 and 2, then the partitioner decides that outputs A and C (for example) go to reducer 1, while B and D go to reducer 2.

The OutputKeyComparatorClass determines if and how the data are sorted for *different rows with the same key* before they are Reduced.  The Shuffle phase only *groups* the Map output by key- it does not guarantee that the data is *sorted*.

In your case, it looks like you are selecting the wrong key.  I think your key should be { customerId, orderDate } and you should use getOutputValueGroupingComparator to compare keys by customerId only for grouping, and setOutputKeyComparatorClass to compare keys by customerId and orderDate descending for input to the reducer.  See also Owen O'Malley's email here on the same subject: http://www.mail-archive.com/core-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg05677.html

Comment: Yes I've read the tutorial, and also Owen's thread. My key is correct and is same what you have mentioned in your comment. My question is "is outputValueGroupingComparator absolutely necessary or will a partitioner itself be sufficient"

Comment: A partitioner alone is not sufficient- multiple mappers can and will return values to the reducer in arbitrary order.